# Receiving "Error -4089 EAFNOSUPPORT address family not supported" in .Net Core 1.1 Web App on Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

I published a Web Api implemented in .Net Core 1.1 to Azure as an App Service but I keep receiving the error message below even when browsing a static html file:

```
2016-11-29 16:43:05.594 +00:00 [Warning] Unable to bind to http://localhost:28243 on the IPv6 loopback interface.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -4089 EAFNOSUPPORT address family not supported) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4089 EAFNOSUPPORT address family not supported
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -4089 EAFNOSUPPORT address family not supported
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.tcp_bind(UvTcpHandle handle, SockAddr& addr, Int32 flags)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<StartAsync>b__8_0(Object state)<---
```

I googled it a bit and realized that there are a couple threads in git but none of them shed a light in resolving this issue. for e.g. one of them suggested to upload hosting.json file but that wasn't conclusive either. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have something like `.UseUrls("http://*:28243")` in your `Program.cs` or in your hosting.json (if you load and pass a custom hosting.json to `WebHostBuilder` using `.UseConfiguration(...)``? If so, try using `.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:28243")`? During one of the RC versions there was an issue where `*:28343` would cause it to bind twice to IPv6

Comment: @Tseng No, I do not have such a thing at all. So, should I just go ahead with adding .UseUrls("0.0.0.0:28243") assuming that will address the issue?

Comment: Well I had a similar issue during DNX times and it was due to the `*` wildcard as hostname. https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/766. Also do you call `UseKestrel()` before or after `UseIISIntetgration()`? The order is important and `.UseIISIntegration()` needs to be called after `UseKestrel()` as it overrides its settings

Comment: I did not change the order of when UserKerstel() should be called. I keep using the same code as Microsoft's .net core template generated.

Comment: @Tseng I added .UseUrls("0.0.0.0:28243") to the code and it did not resolve the issue. I checked the log file and realized that Azure decided to use another Url like http://localhost:26704. Basically it did not obey the URL that I included in the code. Not sure what is contributing in this issue!

Comment: Try creating an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues

Comment: You have upgraded from 1.0.0 recently, and trying to deploy updated website to Azure (in place where old 1.0.0 lived)?

Comment: @Dmitry No, it's a brand new deployment.

Comment: @Tseng I will definitely createone. I'm wondering why Microsoft did not catch it sooner as it's a significant case making people incapable of deploying .Net Core 1.1 web apps!

Comment: @tseng I opened issue #1242 (https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1242)

Answer (score 0):

Check for `global.json` file in solution root - do you have sdk version "for 1.1"? Something like

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```